# Switching db connection at run-time

Tags: c#, sql-server, client-server

I have developed an application which runs query against a DB located in another machine (let's call il SRV-SQL).

In certain cases the application can fail to communicate with the DB machine so my employer wants me to develop a new module which is capable of switching at run-time between the existent connection (to SRV-SQL) to a local DB instance (which is the very same copy of the one in the DB machine).

I have a couple of questions about that:

1. which is the best way to detect connection problems so that I can fire an "event" to switch from remote connection to the locale one? Would I need to trap `SqlException` or there is a better way?
2. Is there any way to switch between the 2 environments without breaking user's actions?

The second point is less trivial as it is acceptable to logout and ask the user to login again (even though i would try to avoid it).

Please let me know if you need more information... also, sorry but I cannot provide any code as this is a design question!

Thanks for taking the time to answer!

Comment: What are you going to do when your data is spread across 2 databases?

Comment: Data in the local DB is going to be copied to the master DB from an another module which is responsible for that particular duty.

Comment: There's services like failover, but that's for enterprise scenarios,  I think your original thought of catching the `SqlException` would probably work, but you should try and make that abstracted away from your application.

Comment: Well, i was hoping for some sample code to show how to solve my problem (or at least to have some hints)... Anyway thank you, your help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Sure, I'll provide something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be good to abstract away the fact that there could possibly be multiple databases from the rest of your application.

```
public class WidgetRepository
{
    private readonly string _primaryConnectionString;
    private readonly string _secondaryConnectionString;

    public WidgetRepository(string primaryConnectionString, string secondaryConnectionString)
    {
        _primaryConnectionString = primaryConnectionString;
        _secondaryConnectionString = secondaryConnectionString;
    }

    public void AddWidget(Widget widget)
    {
        ExecuteAction(AddWidgetAction(widget));
    }

    public void UpdateWidget(Widget widget)
    {
        ExecuteAction(UpdateWidgetAction(widget));
    }

    private Action<string> AddWidgetAction(Widget widget)
    {
        return Action<string>(connectionString => {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                using (var command = connection.CreateCommand())
                {
                    command.CommandText = "INSERT INTO Widgets(name, price) VALUES(@name, @price)";
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", widget.Name);
                    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price", widget.Price);
                    command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }           
            }
        });
    }

    private Action<string> UpdateWidgetAction(Widget widget)
    {
        // Logic here to update a widget
    }

    private void ExecuteAction(Action<string> action)
    {
        try
        {
            action(_primaryConnectionString);
        }
        catch (SqlException)
        {
            action(_secondaryConnectionString);
        }
    }   
}
```

Usage:

```
var widgetRepository = new WidgetRepository("dbconn1", "dbconn2");

widgetRepository.AddWidget(new Widget("Cog", 15.99m));
```

Comment: Nicely done! I think i'll try this one. Sure i want to abstract as i don't want my application to know if it is connected to a specific provider or not. Thanks